# How does .load() determine which file to load?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery's `.load()` method to load html files into the DOM. What I've discovered, through tinkering around is the following. Say I have an index.html and page.html file in the same directory. Then the following code works:

```
$('body').load('page.html');
```

The problem is that this code *also* seems to work if I have page.html in a subdirectory of the directory that index.html is in.

So my question is, if I have, say, three subdirectories with the file page.html inside of them, and call `$('body').load('page.html');` within the parent directory, which file would be "preferred" by `.load()`?

Comment: It's direct URL to file. `page.html` means it's inside root folder.

Comment: How are you serving your page? Apache? .htaccess file configuration serves from index.html directory?

Comment: @DiegoGallegos using Apache on cloud9 to serve, with no .htaccess in any directory.

Comment: @Justinas not sure I follow? If it's in the root folder, how can it successfully load from a subdirectory?

Comment: It can't be loaded from subdirectory, it should load always from current directory wherever index.html is available. The problem you are encountering I believe it's because of browser cache.

Comment: @Seabody Visit `www.yourdomain.com/page.html`. This page is loaded. If you can't access it, than neither `.load` can do it

Comment: Okay, cheers. There were some weird inconsistencies going on - visited `mydomain.com/page.html` and the content was served, yet the file didn't exist in that directory. I don't know what changed (doubtful it was cache, I used CTRL+F5 to reload), but something did and issue is resolved. :)